# I cannot display the header region in my Drupal theme

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming

I am not seeing the content I have for the header region in my drupal theme is it best practice to use the following code in the page.tpl.php?

```
<?php include('region--header.tpl.php'); ?>
```

I see the content when I use the code above but I cannot see it when I use the code below:

```
<?php if ($page['header']): ?>
  <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In my .info file I have the following code:

```
regions[header] = Header
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your base `region.tpl.php` file to the theme's templates folder. 
`region--header.tpl.php` file *and* `region.tpl.php` file should be placed in the templates folder.

Comment: If I know well, the region needs at least a block to be shown too, no?